# Corollary of the Stirling's formula for complex valuable

Tags: gamma-function

For any $\delta>0$ I understand the proof of
$$ \log \Gamma (s) =(s-1/2)\log s -s +\log \sqrt{2 \pi}+O(|s|^{-1})$$ 
in $\{s||\arg (s)| < \pi -\delta\}$.

But I cannot prove following corollary.

for any fixed real number $\sigma_1<\sigma _2$ we get
$$\log \Gamma (\sigma +it) =(\sigma +it-1/2)\log (it) +\log \sqrt{2\pi}+O(|t|^{-1})$$
in $\{s=\sigma + it | \sigma_1 < \sigma <\sigma_2, |t|\ge 1\}$.

Please teach me this proof.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|t|$ is large and $\sigma$ is fixed. We can write, using Stirling's formula,
\begin{align*}
 &\log \Gamma (\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t) = \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log (\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t) - \sigma  - \mathrm{i}t + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}(\left| {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t} \right|^{ - 1} )
\\ & = \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {\mathrm{i}t\left( {1 + \frac{\sigma }{{\mathrm{i}t}}} \right)} \right) - \sigma  - \mathrm{i}t + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  +\mathcal{O}(\left| {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t} \right|^{ - 1} )
\\ & = \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log (\mathrm{i}t) + \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{\sigma }{{\mathrm{i}t}}} \right) - \sigma  - \mathrm{i}t + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}(\left| {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t} \right|^{ - 1} ).
\end{align*}
For small $|z|$, we have
$$
\log (1 + z) = z + \mathcal{O}(\left| z \right|^2 ).
$$
Thus,
$$
\left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{\sigma }{{\mathrm{i}t}}} \right) = \sigma  + \mathcal{O}(\left| t \right|^{ - 1} ).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log \Gamma (\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t) = \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log (\mathrm{i}t) - \mathrm{i}t + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}(\left| {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t} \right|^{ - 1} ).
$$
Since $|t|$ is large and $\sigma$ is fixed, we also have
$$
\mathcal{O}(\left| {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t} \right|^{ - 1} ) = \mathcal{O}(\left| t \right|^{ - 1} ).
$$
Consequently,
$$
\log \Gamma (\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t) = \left( {\sigma  + \mathrm{i}t - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log (\mathrm{i}t) - \mathrm{i}t + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}(\left| t \right|^{ - 1} ).
$$
This is the correct result. In your statement, you are missing the term $-\mathrm{i}t$.